# Google maps and fusion tables, geoaware

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, google-fusion-tables

I'm setting up a community website for people with gluten intolerance.

I have everything working, but I am stuck on one bit.

The website is at http://gfmap.com

I have sorted a form that then updates a Fusion table and that drives the map on the homepage. I have sorted the filter so you can see just specific categories, and even the search box.

This has all been cribbed together because I do not know JavaScript, but probably should.

So the one missing piece of the puzzle for me is **how to make the map location aware**, ie if someone looks at it from New York they get the New York view of the map.

I can make this work using examples on the Google website, but then the layers and search won't work.

I'd be incredibly grateful if someone can take a quick look at the code for the website and tell me how to do everything I can do now, but make it location aware.

Comment: This sort of geolocation isn't too difficult: you can use the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_geolocation However, you probably wont find someone to write this code for you into your website.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the geoLocation, as described in Oliver's comment you just need to change. I have not used this. You say you've got it working via some Google code examples and convert it to new google.maps.LatLng

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('themap'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.87668666121477, 151.1396026611328),
    zoom: 12
  });
```

To use something like:

```
     center: geoLoc,
```

This should not affect your Fusion Table layers at all.